# How to display array of strings selecting a value using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In HTML I can set the option text but sending the value of if like this:

```
<select id="cars">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>    
</select>
```

So I send it to Ts file I get the Value of it.

In angular I'doing like this

```
<select  formControlName="Cars">
            <option *ngFor="let item of values_Car">
            {{item}}
            </option>
        </select>
```

TS

```
values_car : any = ["Volvo", "Saab"];
```

How can I create some kinda Dictionary to show only the text and get the values of it?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understand the question related to the dictionary but you were close with the *ngFor:

Notice the values_car, you were not using the right variable's name. And to bind the value, you need to use brackets around otherwise `"item"` is gonna be taken as a string and not the actual value of the `let item`

ts:

```
export class Car { 
    brand: string;
    id: string;
    constructor(brand: string, id: string) {
        this.brand= brand;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

values_car : any = [new Car('Volvo', '1'), new Car('Saab', '2')];
```

Html:

```
<select  formControlName="Cars">
    <option *ngFor="let item of values_car" [value]="item.id">
        {{ item.brand }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Since you are asking about an enum, Ive added a function that converts an enum to an object to match the html.

```
carEnum: CarEnum = CarEnum

ngOnInit() {
    this.values_car = Object.keys(CarEnum).map(key => {
        return new Car(key, CarEnum[key])
    });
}
```

Comment: I wanna set two values to this item, one to show on select and another to send to the server.  '`<option value="5">Volvo</option>` The value of Volvo is 5. That's what I want to do.

Comment: I added a car class, but it could also be an interface, that contains an id and a brand so you can have a value and a name to display

Comment: Do you have a similar example with enum?

Comment: What would be the enum?

Comment: export enum Cars{
    A = "Audi",
    V = "Volvo"
}

Comment: You really shouldnt do that because you cant loop over an enum directly from the Html without calling a function which is a bad practice. If you only have an enum, I would convert it into an array of objects and then use the array in the html

Comment: @NathielPaulino edited to add the conversion of an enum to an array of Car